# Writing a string to a file causes an exception in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting a "FormatException:  Input string was not in a correct format" error that I don't understand.

I'm using the following lines to write a string to a text file:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myfilename, false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(enc)))
{
    sw.Write(mystring, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

(the encoding part is because I do have an option in my application to set it to utf-8 or iso-8859-1... but I think that's irrelevant).

All of my strings write out just fine except this one string that is different from the others because it actually has a snippet of javascript code in it.  I'm sure that one of the special characters there might be causing the problem but how do I know?

The one thing I tried was to insert the following line just before the sw.Write statement above:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(mystring);
```

and it wrote out to the console just fine - no error.

Help?

Thanks!  (and Happy New Year!)

-Adeena

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The overload you are using takes the format as the first parameter, and objects to inject after that.

You can do either of the following:

```
sw.Write(mystring + Environment.NewLine);
```

or

```
sw.Write("{0}{1}", mystring, Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Both samples above will work; so will sw.WriteLine(mystring). However, unless it's clear "why" there was an error, the problem is not resolved yet, just avoided ;)

Comment: Ah, and another little thing - string concatenation is a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comments from DK, I tested to what extend string concatenation is slower. I made this setup with three options;

- concatenating the string
- calling `sw.Write` twice
- calling `sw.WriteLine`

On my machine, the second option is about 88% faster than average. At 10000000 iterations they use 3517, 2420 and 3385 milliseconds.

It should only be significant if this is code that is called many times in your program.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string myString = "kdhlkhldhcøehdhkjehdkhekdhk";
            int iterations=getIntFromParams(args, 0, 10);
            int method = getIntFromParams(args, 1, 0);
            var fileName=Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.Default))
            {
                switch (method)
                {
                    case 0:

                        Console.WriteLine("Starting method with concatenation. Iterations: " + iterations);
                        var start0 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(myString + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        var time0 = DateTimeOffset.Now - start0;
                        Console.WriteLine("End at " + time0.TotalMilliseconds + " ms.");

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting method without concatenation. Iterations: " + iterations);
                        var start1 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(myString);
                            sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        var time1 = DateTimeOffset.Now - start1;
                        Console.WriteLine("End at " + time1.TotalMilliseconds + " ms.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Starting method without concatenation, using WriteLine. Iterations: " + iterations);
                        var start2 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
                        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(myString);
                        }
                        var time2 = DateTimeOffset.Now - start2;
                        Console.WriteLine("End at " + time2.TotalMilliseconds + " ms.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static int getIntFromParams(string[] args, int index, int @default)
        {
            int value;
            try
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(args[index], out value))
                {
                    value = @default;
                }
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                value = @default;
            }
            return value;
        }
  }
```